# Dealing with a specific rule of a card game

Tags: java, logic

I am working on a card game and I'm facing a problem regarding the gameplay. So basically the rules of the game are that who finishes the hand first gets placed first, second second and so on. I am keeping a list of the players in a `List<Player`, and if one finishes I just skip the turn from him (checks if >= 1 cards in hand), until 1 player is left. Now, the rule is that if one finishes with an unbeatable card/move or everyone else passes for example, the turn should be to the next player and he is free to make a move. I've been struggling and haven't found a proper solution yet. How to achieve this?

I am currently saving the waste (last played list of cards) cards into a `List<Card>`, and I am keeping a `Player` instance lastPlayed for the last playing player, and a `Player` instance hasTurn for the current player on turn.
The turns are shifted in this method inside the `Game` class:

```
public void determineNextPlayerTurn()
{
    if(playersLeft() > 1)
    {
        int i = players.indexOf(hasTurn) + 1;

        if(i == 4)
            i = 0;

        hasTurn = players.get(i);

        if(hasTurn.isPlaying())
        {
            if(!isHumanTurn())
            {
                display.disableButtons();
                AI temp = (AI)players.get(i);
                temp.onPlayerTurn(this);
            }
            else
                display.enableButtons();
        }
        else
        {
            determineNextPlayerTurn();
        }
    }
    else
        newGame(0);
```

The method of AI that is called when it is an ai's turn:

```
public void onPlayerTurn(Game game)
{
    selectCardsToPlay(game.getWaste(), game.getLastPlayedPlayer());
    if(getSelectedCards().isEmpty())
    {
        game.determineNextPlayerTurn();
    }
    else
    {
        if(Moves.canBePlayed(getSelectedCards(), game.getWaste(), this, game.getLastPlayedPlayer()))
        {
            playMove(game);
            game.determineNextPlayerTurn();
        }
        else
            game.determineNextPlayerTurn();
    }
}
```

While for the user, nothing is called as the `determineNextPlayerTurn()` is called within the `ActionListener` of the playing buttons (Play, Pass).

Note: Currently like this, if the scenario occurs with the human last playing there will be a stackoverflow for the reason that every ai is doing a Pass. Every other code is fine for now, but I need help with implementing a simple solution to that specific case, and if I am doing something wrong I am open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you have a counter for the number of "passes" that are executed and then compare that to the number of players. If the passes are equal to the number of players - 1 then that would mean that following player should be free to make a move. Also what is an "unbeatable move" if there is such a thing then wouldn't you be able to classify the turn as that and then attach a boolean that checks the player for whether or not they have made one of these types of moves?

Comment: Why exactly number of player - 1? Should I remove a player from the players List or shall I just skip the turn to next if hasTurn has no cards in hand? And there is no such thing as unbeatable move, but it is unbeatable depending on the current hand. So for example the highest ranking single card is red joker. If one finishes his hand with red joker as the last card, no one can beat it. But this can also occur if some card beatable by rank is played last by x player, and other players can't beat it with their current cards.

Comment: You shouldn't remove a player from the list but you should have a statement that checks if they have no cards in hand and then automatically skips their turn if that is the case. Does the Red Joker end the game? If not then you can just have the players continue playing to achieve their ranking.